# TObjectQueue скорость работы при большом количестве элементов

Tags: delphi

Работают несколько потоков. Один тип потоков делает **push**, а второй тип **pop** через критические секции. Как только очередь превышает какое то большое количество - начинаются дикие тормоза. Скорее всего виновато **capacity**. Ведь при достижении некого количества элементов идет перестроение очереди. Как посоветуете уйти от этого? Может сделать список очередей? Или **capacity** сразу поставить много?

```
EnterCriticalSection(CS);
try
LIst_1.Push(object);
finally
leaveCriticalSection(CS);
end;
```

---

```
EnterCriticalSection(CS);
try
 if List_1.Count>0 theh
 ob:= LIst_1.pop(object);
 finally
   leaveCriticalSection(CS);
 end;
```

Comment: дак поставьте и проверьте, в чем сложность? _зы: там кстати еще есть `TThreadedQueue`_

Comment: а про какой объем очереди и число потоков вообще речь идет?

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что это из-за не совсем правильно понимаемой работы критических секций, поведение которых в Vista стало отличаться от того, что было ранее в XP https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx . Иными словами - поток, который делает pop, не успевает захватить CriticalSection

Comment: в лабораторных условиях тяжело такую нагрузку дать. 20 потоков делают **Push** и 30 потоков делают **Pop**

Comment: а в чем правильность понимания критической секции? 
----------------------------
EnterCriticalSection(CS)
try
LIst_1.Push(object);
finally
leaveCriticalSection(CS);
end;

Comment: Почитайте по приведенной мной ссылке - порядок захвата критической секции != порядок входа в ожидание CS. Теоретически поток, который делает pop может вообще не дождаться захвата CS, все время зависая на EnterCriticalSection.

Comment: вы не юзаете стандартные классы что ли? если `EnterCriticalSection(cs)` вместо `cs.enter()` ?

Comment: а TRTLCriticalSection не является стандартным классом?

Comment: Является. Попробуйте после выхода из CS при добавлении записи в принудительном порядке делать https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686352(v=vs.85).aspx . Изначально хотел посоветовать http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer , но в вашем случае он не лучше CS...

Comment: "Дикие тормоза" это вообще о чём? Загрузка CPU? Время ожидания читающих потоков? Или записывающих? Вы наверное о профилировании кода не слышали, раз выражаетесь в таких терминах. Так вот знайте, что можно замерить время потраченное на каждую строку вашего кода и из этого сделать вывод о том, какое место является самым узким - критические секции или перераспределение памяти в очереди или что-то ещё. Рекомендую заняться профилированием, а потом уже решать, как ускорить узкое место, когда это самое узкое место будет доподлинно локализовано.

Comment: Большое количество - это сколько в штуках? Добавьте больше потоков, достающих объекты из списка, или уменьшите количество потоков добавляющих объекты туда.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci 20 на запись и 30 на считывание (из комментариев) - куда уж больше-то? :) Я не думаю, что у подопытного компьютера больше 8 ядер.

Comment: Насчет профилирования. У меня есть доступ **только** к своему логу работы программы.  На локальной машине дать такую нагрузку не могу как на боевом сервере, вернее пыхтеть нужно слишком долго.